# Input field height on mobile website

Tags: gui-design, mobile, input-fields, ux-field

Can you, please provide a case study or a research regarding the input field optimal height on website mobile ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Google's material design input section:

https://material.google.com/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field

Answer (score 0):

It's advice that the *Input field height* should not be set, as it can easily be adapted to the font size of the text to be inputted, however, the text font can be styled however you which, it all depends on what you want.

But generally, the accepted font size for Texts on mobile(web) is ***16px*** [image: Image from https://material.io/]